# When to use the lifecycle method beforeMount in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to come up with an example when to use each Vue.js lifecycle hook. For `beforeMount()` I can't come up with any use case. While researching I have als read:

> Most likely we’ll never need to use this hook.

Can someone provide an example when I would like to use this lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best use case that I can come up with comes from [Directly injecting data to Vue apps with Symfony/Twig](https://nehalist.io/directly-injecting-data-to-vue-apps-with-symfony-twig/).  Before the mount happens, you can still see the actual, untransformed Element before it gets replaced by Vue.  A particular piece that you can access is the [data properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).  In the example below, we lose `data-fizz` if we don't pull stuff out of it before we get to `mounted`.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      foo: "bar"
    };
  },
  template: "<div>{{foo}}</div>",
  beforeMount() {
    console.log(this.$el); // <div id="app" data-fizz="buzz"></div>
    console.log(this.$el.dataset.fizz); // buzz
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$el); // <div>bar</div>
    console.log(this.$el.dataset.fizz); // undefined
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" data-fizz="buzz"></div>
```