# How to access data before mounting in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If I were to have:

```
<div id="app" data-user="testing"></div>`
```

and after mounting the vue app on `#app`, I get this:

```
<div data-app="true" class="v-application v-application--is-ltr theme--light" id="app">
```

How can I access/preserve the data-user value to use in my app later?

Comment: You can just use plain javascript: `beforeMount() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('app').getAttribute('data-user'))
  }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use the lifecycle method beforeMount in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077104/when-to-use-the-lifecycle-method-beforemount-in-vue-js)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, found my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

If anyone else runs into this, here is how I solved it

```
new Vue({
 vuetify,
 store,
 render: h => h(App),
 data: {
   user: ''
 },
 beforeMount() { this.user = this.$el.dataset.user } <--- ADD THIS TO SET THE VALUE
}).$mount('#app')
```