# What is the difference between the beforeMount and the created lifecycle hook in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am still unclear on where I should use the beforeMount and where the created lifecycle hook. It seems to me that in both, the reactive data has been loaded and it is before the DOM has been mounted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use the lifecycle method beforeMount in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077104/when-to-use-the-lifecycle-method-beforemount-in-vue-js)

Comment: @skirtle Well this explains *when its useful to use beforeMount* but not the difference between the two

Comment: Vue.js lifecycle hooks can be misleading especially when you're newbie, find a detailed description along with a real-time example [here](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases it doesn't matter whether you use `beforeMount` or `created` but there are some where it matters:

### Accessing original DOM element your root Vue component is mounting on

- can be useful for integration with any server-side rendered framework (php, rails etc.)
- explanation and example - [When to use the lifecycle method beforeMount in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077104/when-to-use-the-lifecycle-method-beforemount-in-vue-js)
- in `created` hook `this.$el` is `undefined`, in `beforeMount` it's the original unmodified element, in `mounted` it's root element created by your component/template

### Server-side rendering (Nuxt, Vuepress etc.)

- [docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#component-lifecycle-hooks)
- `beforeCreate` and `created` are only hooks called on the server
- that means you should not use any code which needs `window`, `document` or any browser API in `created` as those will not be present on the server
- on the other hand code placed in the `beforeMount` (or `mounted`) is executed **only on the client** (browser)

Answer (score 2):

The `beforeMount` hook runs ***right before*** the initial render happens and after the template or render functions have been compiled(when vm.$el has not been created yet).

`created` is the step ***after*** initialization of your component(where you are able to access reactive data and events that are active with the created hook. Templates and Virtual DOM have not yet been mounted or rendered)