# What is the actual use of onBeforeMount in the context of Composition API setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Consider the following  section of a Vue component:

```
<setup script lang="ts">
// place called A
const A = 1
onBeforeMount(() => {
  // place called B
  const B = 2
}
</script>
```

I am trying to understand what the sequence of the variable creation is. The [Vue Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram) shows the diagram

[image]

I am not clear from it whether (taking my example)

- `A` is created first, then `B`
- `B` is created first, then `A`
- the sequence is not guaranteed

I believe that the sequence is "everything in the core `setup`" ("place called A" in my example), and then `onBeforeMount()`.

If this is the case, what is the added value of `onBeforeMount` as its contents could also be in the core of `setup`?

Comment: As you correctly inferred, `A` is created before `B`. The diagram also illustrates this sequence (notice the `setup` block followed by `beforeMount`). The `setup` hook occurs essentially at the same as the `beforeCreate` hook. And the difference between the hooks is described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046406/6277151).